# stored procedure with insert & update using identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called 'tasks' in that `'task id'` is identity column, for that table I have to write save stored procedure, in which when 'task id' is not given it should insert the values and when 'task id' is given it should update the table.

how can this achievable when task id is identity column could anyone explain with example. 
here is the code

```
Alter PROCEDURE TaskSave
(
@taskid int,   
@ProjectId int,
@EmployeeId int,
@TaskName nvarchar(50),
@Duration_Hrs int,
@StartDate nvarchar(20),
@FinishDate nvarchar(20),
@CreateUserId int,
@CreatedDate nvarchar(20),
@ModifiedUserID int,
@ModifiedDate nvarchar(20),
@Is_CommonTask bit
) AS

BEGIN
    IF Exists( select null from TblTasks where TaskId=@TaskId)
    BEGIN
        INSERT TblTasks
        VALUES (@ProjectId,@EmployeeId,@TaskName,@Duration_Hrs,
                @StartDate,@FinishDate,@CreateUserId,@CreatedDate,
                @ModifiedUserID,@ModifiedDate,@Is_CommonTask)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TblTasks SET 
        StartDate=@StartDate,FinishDate=@FinishDate,
        Duration_Hrs=@Duration_Hrs 
        WHERE TaskId=@TaskId
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: What is your question? If it is just testing `@TaskID` variable, I suggest changing the IF statement to something like `IF @TaskID = -1` (or some other value that will be used as a value for your "not given" user case. If you want to know what is task id after you insert, then use `@@IDENTITY`. If you also want to return `@TaskID`, make the parameter OUTPUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, give your input variable TaskID a default value like below, then simply check to see if the variable is NULL, if so, insert a new row

```
Alter PROCEDURE TaskSave
(
@taskid int = NULL,   
@ProjectId int,
@EmployeeId int,
@TaskName nvarchar(50),
@Duration_Hrs int,
@StartDate nvarchar(20),
@FinishDate nvarchar(20),
@CreateUserId int,
@CreatedDate nvarchar(20),
@ModifiedUserID int,
@ModifiedDate nvarchar(20),
@Is_CommonTask bit
) AS

BEGIN

    IF @taskid IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT TblTasks
        VALUES (@ProjectId,@EmployeeId,@TaskName,@Duration_Hrs,
                @StartDate,@FinishDate,@CreateUserId,@CreatedDate,
                @ModifiedUserID,@ModifiedDate,@Is_CommonTask)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TblTasks SET 
        StartDate=@StartDate,FinishDate=@FinishDate,
        Duration_Hrs=@Duration_Hrs 
        WHERE TaskId=@TaskId
    END


END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, check if the record doesn't exist and perform insert, otherwise update. You can also declare the `@TaskId` parameter as `OUTPUT` and return it when inserting, using the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TaskSave(
    @TaskId INT = NULL OUTPUT
    , @ProjectId INT
    , @EmployeeId INT
    , @TaskName NVARCHAR(50)
    , @Duration_Hrs INT
    , @StartDate NVARCHAR(20)
    , @FinishDate NVARCHAR(20)
    , @CreateUserId INT
    , @CreatedDate NVARCHAR(20)
    , @ModifiedUserID INT
    , @ModifiedDate NVARCHAR(20)
    , @Is_CommonTask BIT
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF NOT(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TblTasks WHERE TaskId = @TaskId))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TblTasks(
            ProjectId
            , EmployeeId
            , TaskName
            , Duration_Hrs
            , StartDate
            , FinishDate
            , CreateUserId
            , CreatedDate
            , ModifiedUserID
            , ModifiedDate
            , Is_CommonTask
        )
        VALUES(
            @ProjectId
            , @EmployeeId
            , @TaskName
            , @Duration_Hrs
            , @StartDate
            , @FinishDate
            , @CreateUserId
            , @CreatedDate
            , @ModifiedUserID
            , @ModifiedDate
            , @Is_CommonTask
        )
        SET @TaskId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TblTasks SET 
            StartDate = @StartDate
            , FinishDate = @FinishDate
            , Duration_Hrs = @Duration_Hrs
        WHERE TaskId=@TaskId
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `@taskid` parameter as NULL. the if it is null then insert else update. see below.

```
Alter PROCEDURE TaskSave
(
@taskid int =NULL,   
@ProjectId int,
@EmployeeId int,
@TaskName nvarchar(50),
@Duration_Hrs int,
@StartDate nvarchar(20),
@FinishDate nvarchar(20),
@CreateUserId int,
@CreatedDate nvarchar(20),
@ModifiedUserID int,
@ModifiedDate nvarchar(20),
@Is_CommonTask bit
) AS

BEGIN
  if @taskid is null
  BEGIN
        INSERT TblTasks
        VALUES (@ProjectId,@EmployeeId,@TaskName,@Duration_Hrs,
                @StartDate,@FinishDate,@CreateUserId,@CreatedDate,
                @ModifiedUserID,@ModifiedDate,@Is_CommonTask)
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TblTasks SET 
        StartDate=@StartDate,FinishDate=@FinishDate,
        Duration_Hrs=@Duration_Hrs 
        WHERE TaskId=@taskid
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these, I used to create a general stored procedure which is capable of inserting, updating and deleting an item. The general pattern looked like this

```
create procedure Modify_MyTable
  @Action char(1),
  @Data int,
  @PK int output
as
  if @Action = 'I' begin -- Insert
    insert into MyTable (Data) values (@Data)
    set @PK = Scope_Identity()
  end
  if @Action = 'M' begin -- Modify
    update MyTable set Data = @Data where PKID = @PK
  end
  if @Action = 'D' begin -- Delete
    delete MyTable where PKID = @PK
  end
```

It is quite a while ago when I used this but I found it quite handy as I have all the manipulation code in one SP (I could have used three, of course) and could also add logging features and other basic logic in this procedure.

I am not saying that this is still the best method but it should show the basic logic.